# php data isnt processing, can someone look over my code?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to set up a registration page, that also hashes ans adds salts to the hashed data, but nothing is processing on the server AND im getting no console errors, can someone tell me where im going wrong?

### html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script 
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="createScript.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-left: 100px;">
            <form method="POST" action="index.html">
                <label>Enter your first name</label><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br><br>
                <label>Enter your last name</label><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br><br>
                <label>Enter a username (this will only be used to login)</label><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"><br><br>
                <label>Re-enter that username</label><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="reuserName" name="reuserName"><br><br>
                <label>Enter your email address</label><br><br>
                <input type="email" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress"><br><br>
                <label>Re-enter your email address</label><br><br>
                <input type="email" id="reemailAddress" name="reemailAddress"><br><br>
                <label>Enter a password</label><br><br>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
                <label>Enter the password again</label><br><br>
                <input type="password" id="rePassword" name="rePassword"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" id="register" name="register">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### connect.php code

```
<?php
    if (!defined('HOST')) define("HOST", "localhost");
    if (!defined('USER')) define("USER", "root");
    if (!defined('PASSWORD')) define("PASSWORD", "");
    if (!defined('DB')) define("DB", "socialmedia");

    $connect = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB);

    if ($connect->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

?> <!-- PHP -->
```

---

### create.php code

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';


if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {                                            

        //Check for input
        if((isset($_POST['firstName'])) && (!empty($_POST['firstName'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['lastName'])) && (!empty($_POST['lastName'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['userName'])) && (!empty($_POST['userName'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['reuserName'])) && (!empty($_POST['reuserName'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['emailAddress'])) && (!empty($_POST['emailAddress'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['reemailAddress'])) && (!empty($_POST['reemailAddress'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['password'])) && (!empty($_POST['password'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['rePassword'])) && (!empty($_POST['rePassword']))) {      

            //Check first name
            if(isset($_POST['firstName'])==0 || $_POST['firstName']==" ") {

                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid first name";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['firstName']);
            }//End of first name failure

            else {
                //Continue
                $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['firstName']);
            }//End of first name success

            //Check last name
            if(isset($_POST['lastName'])==0 || $_POST['lastName']==" ") {

                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid last name";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['lastName']);
            }//End of last name failure

            else {
                //Continue
                $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lastName']);
                $fullName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $firstName . " " . $lastName);
            }//End of last name success

            //Check username
            if(isset($_POST['userName'])==0 || $_POST['userName']==" ") {

                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid username";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['userName']);
            }//End of username failure

            else {
                //Continue
                $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['userName']);
            }//End of usernamesuccess

            //Check reusername
            if(isset($_POST['reuserName'])==0 || $_POST['reuserName']==" ") {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid username";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['reuserName']);
            }//End of reusername failure
            elseif ($_POST['userName'] === $_POST['reuserName']) {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter matching usernames";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['reuserName']);
            }
            else
            {
                //Continue
                $reuserName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['reuserName']);
                $hashedUserName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, hash('sha512', $userName));
            }//End of reusername success

            //Check email
            if(!filter_var($_POST['emailAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid email address";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['emailAddress']);
            }//End of email failure

            else {
                //Continue
                $emailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['emailAddress']);
            }//End of email success

            //Check reemail
            if(!filter_var($_POST['reemailAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid email address";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['reemailAddress']);
            }//End of reemail failure
            elseif ($_POST['emailAddress'] === $_POST['reemailAddress']) {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter matching email addresses";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['reemailAddress']);
            }
            else {
                //Continue
                $reemailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['reemailAddress']);
            }//End of reemail success                   

            //Check password
            if(isset($_POST['password'])==0 || $_POST['password']==" ") 
            {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid password";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['password']);
            }//End of password failure
            else
            {
                //Continue
                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
            }//End of password success

            //Check repassword 
            if(isset($_POST['rePassword'])==0 || $_POST['rePassword']==" ") 
            {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter a valid password";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['rePassword']);
            }//End of repassword  failure
            elseif ($_POST['password'] === $_POST['rePassword']) {
                //Error
                ob_start();
                echo "Please enter matching passwords";
                exit;
                ob_end_flush();

                //Free Resources
                unset($_POST['rePassword']);
            }
            else
            {
                //Continue
                $rePassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['rePassword']);
                $hashPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, hash('sha512', $password));
                $saltedHashPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, hash('sha512', $userName . "" . $password));
            }//End of repassword success  

            //Insert data into users database
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(idusers, name, username, hashedusername, email, password, unsaltedhashpassword, saltedhashpassword)
             VALUES ('$fullName', '$userName', '$hashedUserName', '$email', '$password', '$hashedPassword', '$saltedHashPassword');";

            if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE)
            {
                ob_start();
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('New contact created.');</script>";
                ob_end_flush();
            }//End of INSERT success
            else 
            {
                ob_start();
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error: ' . $sql . $connect->error;');</script>";
                ob_end_flush();
            }//End of INSERT Failed

        }//Check Data
    }//Get Post
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="createScript.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

---

### javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#register").click(function(){   
          firstName=$("#firstName").val();
          lastName=$("#lastName").val();
          userName=$("#userName").val();
          reuserName=$("#reuserName").val();
          emailAddress=$("#emailAddress").val();
          reemailAddress=$("#reemailAddress").val();
          pass=$("#password").val();
          rePassword=$("#rePassword").val();
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "create.php",
            data: 
            "firstName="+firstName+
            "&lastName="+lastName+
            "&userName="+userName+
            "&reuserName="+reuserName+
            "&emailAddress="+emailAddress+
            "&reemailAddress="+reemailAddress+
            "&password="+pass+
            "&rePassword="+rePassword,
           success: function(html){    
            if(html=='true')    {
             console.log("Submitted!");
            }
            else if(html=='false'){
             console.log("Error!");
            }
            else{
             console.log("Error!"+html);
            }
           },
           beforeSend:function()
           {
           },
           error: function(e)
           {
                console.log("Error!");
                console.log(e);             
           }
          });
        return true;
    });
});
```

---

### users.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `idusers` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `hashedusername` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `unsaltedhashpassword` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `saltedhashpassword` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusers`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idusers_UNIQUE` (`idusers`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hashedusername_UNIQUE` (`hashedusername`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `saltedhashpassword_UNIQUE` (`saltedhashpassword`)
)
```

---

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Email addresses, names, and other values are often *significantly* longer than you expect. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default "string" type field and only restrict that if you have a concrete and compelling reason to do so.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA or MD5**.

Comment: You have a lot of code. We need to get this cut down to a more manageable amount. did you check the web server log. Have you been viewing the data sent back and forth between the server and the client.

Comment: You also need to look into using jQuery's auto-encoding method more effectively. Jamming together a string using concatenation leads to serious problems. You should express that as a JSON object, key-value style, and let it encode that data for you.

Comment: I'm also really confused by why usernames are being hashed. That's a very strange practice and it seems to have no particular utility here.

Comment: What's this for .... <script type="text/javascript" src="createScript.js"></script> ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i am hashing the username as it is only being used to login, and will not be public ally shown. also i am currently storing a password in plain text just to make sure its getting the right data. once data is confirmed correct the username will be the salt added to the password hash to make the hash unique rather than using a static salt for the hash as doing with assume passwords are different. <script type="text/javascript" src="createScript.js"></script> is used to define the jquery file

Comment: isset returns a boolean true/fase so it makes no sense to put isset(smthg)==0 since it will always be false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

Remove your action tag from the form as it is submitting the data to index.html which is wrong.

change your `.click()` to this:

```
$("#register").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

          firstName=$("#firstName").val();
          lastName=$("#lastName").val();
          userName=$("#userName").val();
          reuserName=$("#reuserName").val();
          emailAddress=$("#emailAddress").val();
          reemailAddress=$("#reemailAddress").val();
          pass=$("#password").val();
          rePassword=$("#rePassword").val();
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "create.php",
            data: 
            "firstName="+firstName+
            "&lastName="+lastName+
            "&userName="+userName+
            "&reuserName="+reuserName+
            "&emailAddress="+emailAddress+
            "&reemailAddress="+reemailAddress+
            "&password="+pass+
            "&rePassword="+rePassword,
           success: function(html){    
            if(html=='true')    {
             console.log("Submitted!");
            }
            else if(html=='false'){
             console.log("Error!");
            }
            else{
             console.log("Error!"+html);
            }
           },
           beforeSend:function()
           {
           },
           error: function(e)
           {
                console.log("Error!");
                console.log(e);             
           }
          });
        return true;
    });
```

I have just added `e.preventDefault()` as your type of button is `"submit"` so it submits the form. In an ajax call you need not to reload or redirect to any page to save data or send data. ajax does it for you.

This should save your data as you have `create.php` already made.

> You can also add `onsubmit="return false"` attribute in your form if
>   e.preventDefault() is not your choice. Or Change the button type from
>   `submit` to `button` and this won't submit your form.

PS: try to serialize the form if it sounds good to you so that you can save the chaos of preparing data yourself. Try this if you want you:

```
 url : "page_url.php",
 data : $('#your_form_id').serialize(),
```

This will work for you and you get rid of those lines of code `.val()` stuff.

Cheers!!

Comment: so ive added 

e.preventDefault();

and i the console error trigers on the second error in the javascript file

else{
 console.log("Error!"+html);
}

Comment: wait nevermind, it worked! 
thank you! 
how do i make the form clear once its submitted? thats why i thought it didnt work. 
also can you help me get my console logs working?
though its working, even on the success which should process this
    if(html=='true') {
        console.log("Submitted!");
    }
it jumps to here instead
    else{
        console.log("Error! 2"+html);
    }

Comment: which data are you returning from your php code? You can do something like $resp[] = array('message'=>200,'data'=>'true'); echo json_encode($resp); This will send you json data which you can traverse and check for resp.

Comment: like the log gives the "failed error" being the second error in the javascript BUT it outputs the success message from the php in the log with it. should i just not worry?? is there an easy way for the form to also be cleared on success?

Comment: `$('#form_id')[0].reset()` this will help you to reset your form.